# How to decode minus sign in PHP after pdftotext

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, decode, pdftotext

I am trying to convert a string with a negative number into an integer.

I converted a pdf file into a text file using `pdftotext`. After doing regex, I have some strings that I need to convert into integers in PHP and later insert them into MySQL. I tried str_replace, preg_replace, and rawurlencode but that did not work.

```
var_dump($mystring);             # output is `string(6) "‐200"`
var_dump(urlencode($mystring));  # output is `string(12) "%E2%80%90200"`
var_dump((int)$mystring);        # output is 'int(0)

$mystring = str_replace('-', '%E2%80%90', $mystring); # did not work
$mystring = preg_replace('/%E2%80%90/', '-', $mystring); # did not work
$mystring = rawurlencode($mystring); # did not work
```

Comment: string(6) "‐200" - seems, you have invisible chars in it, because -200 just 4 chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PDF text contains multi-byte characters, which you will have to convert (potentially in other places as well).

```
<?php

$mystring = "‐200";

$unicode_hyphen = '‐'; // "E2 80 90" is the Unicode multi-byte hyphen character, that your PDFs seem to contain
$ascii_hyphen = '-';
$myint = intval(str_replace($unicode_hyphen , $ascii_hyhpen , $mystring));

var_dump($myint); // => int(-200)
```

See: [3v4l.org/sN5AS](https://3v4l.org/sN5AS)

Comment: To clarify, the ‐ in the text is a Unicode hyphen (U+2010) rather than an ASCII hyphen (U+002D).